# Journal Cover Letter with scrartcl

Tags: koma-script, titles, cv, komacv

I would like to write a cover letter for a journal article using the KOMA-class `scrartcl` document type, since I want to use the same preamble as for my article.

Are there any templates available?

P.S. have added my own suggestion below. Suggestions for improvement and new answers welcomed

Comment: Use class `scrartcl` together with package `scrletter`.

Comment: @esdd, tried that to begin with, but had some compatability issues. It think it was with  ```\setkomafont{disposition}{\bfseries}``` that I have in the preamble.

Comment: Actually, the corresponding KOMA-script class would be `scrlttr2`. I recommend it.

Comment: `\setkomafont{disposition}{\bfseries}` does not work with class `scrlttr2` but with the combination of class `scrartcl` and package `scrletter` or with class `scrletter` which is a wrapper class of `scrartcl` loading package `scrletter`. But you can also replace `\setkomafont{disposition}{\bfseries}` by class option `sfdefaults=false`. This works with both classes `scrartcl` and `scrlttr2`.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion based on the example in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/649773 but  using class `scrartcl` and package `scrletter`:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,bibliography=totoc,parskip=full-,english,
  sfdefaults=false% needs version 3.39 or newer
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrletter}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep} % or \setlist{noitemsep} to leave space around whole list

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlbordercolor =lightgray}
\newcommand{\mailto}[1]{\href{mailto:#1}{#1}}

%----------------------------------------------
% Edit custom info
\title{Title of the Article}
\author{Author}

%-----
% Journal info
\newcommand{\publicationtype}{Research Paper}
\newcommand{\journal}{Science \& Fiction}

\newcommand{\tofirstname}{Ester}
\newcommand{\tolastname}{Editor}
\newcommand{\totitle}{Editor of \journal}
\newcommand{\toseniority}{Professor} % Dr.
\newcommand{\toname}{\tofirstname\ \tolastname}
\newcommand{\tounit}{Center for Sciences}
\newcommand{\toorg}{University of America}
\newcommand{\tostreet}{Box 123 Capitol}
\newcommand{\toplace}{DC, USA}
\newcommand{\toemail}{\mailto{science@america.com}}
\newcommand{\tophone}{}

%--------------------------
% Suggested reviewers:
\newcommand{\referees}{
    \href{https://www.america.com}{Prof. Referee1};  \href{https://www.america.com}{Prof. Referee2}; \href{https://www.america.com}{Prof. Referee3}, and 
    \href{https://www.america.com}{Prof. Referee4}}

%-----------------------
% Article info

% Title extracted from preamble with the package titling and macro \thetitle (below)

\newcommand{\coauthorsandemails}{
    Coauthor 1, \mailto{coauthor1@research.unit.com} and
    Coauthor 2, \mailto{coauthor2@research.unit.com}}


%----------------------
% First Author info
\newcommand{\fromname}{Randy O'right}
\newcommand{\fromtitle}{Researcher}
\newcommand{\fromunit}{Research Institute}
\newcommand{\fromorg}{University of Europe}
\newcommand{\fromstreet}{Street 1}
\newcommand{\fromplace}{00123, Bryssels, Europe}
\newcommand{\fromemail}{\mailto{randy.oright@europe.com}}
\newcommand{\fromphone}{+123 456 789}

% ---------------------
% Letter settings

\LoadLetterOption{DINmtext}
\KOMAoptions{firsthead=false,firstfoot=false,enlargefirstpage,foldmarks=false}

\setkomavar{toname}{\toseniority\ \toname}
\setkomavar{toaddress}{\tounit\\\toorg\\\tostreet\\\toplace}

\setkomavar{fromname}{\fromname}
  \setkomavar{location}{\raggedleft \fromname\\\fromtitle\\\fromunit\\\fromorg\\\fromstreet\\\fromplace\\\fromemail\\\fromphone\\
  \vfill
}

\setkomavar{signature}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{example-image-duck}\\
  \usekomavar{fromname}}
\renewcommand{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}
\setplength{sigbeforevskip}{.5\baselineskip}

\renewcaptionname{english}{\enclname}{Enclosure}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}[backaddress=false,locfield=wide]{}
\newgeometry{margin=.9in, top=.7in} % different margins for this document
\opening{\textbf{Dear \tolastname,}}
\Blindtext[2]
\closing{Kind Regards}
\encl{\begin{itemize} \item Article Manuscript \item Title Page\end{itemize}}
\end{letter}

\restoregeometry
\maketitle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: For koma  v3.39 or newer there is now the class option `sfdefaults=false` instead of `egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles`

Answer (score 0):

```
% text modified from:
% https://authorservices.taylorandfrancis.com/publishing-your-research/making-your-submission/writing-a-journal-article-cover-letter/
% and
% https://thinkscience.co.jp/en/articles/writing-journal-cover-letters

%----------------------------------------------
% Preliminaries
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,bibliography=totoc,parskip=full-]{scrartcl}

%------------------
%\usepackage{0Preamble} % settings common to the project, below are the essential for this document:
\usepackage{titling} % use things from title
\usepackage{xcolor} %  colors.
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} %margins one inch

\title{Title of the Article} % title of your article

\usepackage{comment} % leave blocks of code out between \begin{comment}...\end{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{hyperref}           % Provides clickable links in the PDF-document for \ref
%------------------

\pagestyle{empty} % no page numbers (footnotes, headers)

\newgeometry{margin=.9in, top=.7in} % different margins for this document

\usepackage{enumitem} % reduce spacing in lists

\setlist{nosep} % or \setlist{noitemsep} to leave space around whole list

%\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black}
\hypersetup{urlbordercolor =lightgray}

%----------------------------------------------
% Adding texxt to both sides of the page
\newcommand{\leftright}[3][t]{%
%   {\parskip=0pt
        \noindent\parbox[#1]{.5\textwidth}{\raggedright\texttt{}\emph{#2}}%
        %\parbox[#1]{.333\textwidth}{\centering#3}%
        \parbox[#1]{.5\textwidth}{\raggedleft\texttt{}\emph{#3}} %
%   }
}

\newcommand{\mailto}[1]{\href{mailto:#1}{#1}}

%----------------------------------------------
% Edit custom info

%-----
% Journal info
\newcommand{\publicationtype}{Research Paper}
\newcommand{\journal}{Science \& Fiction}

\newcommand{\tofirstname}{Ester}
\newcommand{\tolastname}{Editor}
\newcommand{\totitle}{Editor of \journal}
\newcommand{\toseniority}{Professor} % Dr.
\newcommand{\toname}{\tofirstname\ \tolastname}
\newcommand{\tounit}{Center for Sciences}
\newcommand{\toorg}{University of America}
\newcommand{\tostreet}{Box 123 Capitol}
\newcommand{\toplace}{DC, USA}
\newcommand{\toemail}{\mailto{science@america.com}}
\newcommand{\tophone}{}

%--------------------------
% Suggested reviewers:
\newcommand{\referees}{
    \href{https://www.america.com}{Prof. Referee1};  \href{https://www.america.com}{Prof. Referee2}; \href{https://www.america.com}{Prof. Referee3}, and 
    \href{https://www.america.com}{Prof. Referee4}}

%-----------------------
% Article info

% Title extracted from preamble with the package titling and macro \thetitle (below)

\newcommand{\coauthorsandemails}{
    Coauthor 1, \mailto{coauthor1@research.unit.com} and
    Coauthor 2, \mailto{coauthor2@research.unit.com}}


%----------------------
% First Author info

\newcommand{\fromname}{Randy O'right}
\newcommand{\fromtitle}{Researcher}
\newcommand{\fromunit}{Research Institute}
\newcommand{\fromorg}{University of Europe}
\newcommand{\fromstreet}{Street 1}
\newcommand{\fromplace}{00123, Bryssels, Europe}
\newcommand{\fromemail}{\mailto{randy.oright@europe.com}}
\newcommand{\fromphone}{+123 456 789}

\newcommand{\signature}{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{example-image-duck}} % change to your signature

%-------------------------------------------------------
%-------------------------------------------------------
% 

\begin{document}
    
    
%   \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%   \setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
    
    
    \textbf{\leftright[t]{To}{From}}
    %\vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \leftright[t]{\toname}{\fromname}
    \leftright[t]{Editor of \journal}{\fromtitle}
    \leftright[t]{\tounit}{\fromunit}
    \leftright[t]{\toorg}{\fromorg}
    \leftright[t]{\tostreet}{\fromstreet}
    \leftright[t]{\toplace}{\fromplace}
    \leftright[t]{\toemail}{\fromemail}
    \leftright[t]{\tophone}{\fromphone}
    
    \vspace{1\baselineskip}
    
    
    \emph{\leftright[t]{\textbf{Dear \toseniority\ \tolastname,}}{\today}}
    
    I would like to submit the manuscript entitled \emph{\thetitle} to be considered for publication as a \publicationtype\ in \journal.
    
    
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% EDIT BELOW %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    %xxxxxxxxx[[Summarize the research problem/gap, your main research findings, and the implications of your findings]]. 
    %In this paper, I/we report on / show that _______. This is significant because __________.  
    %We believe that this manuscript is appropriate for publication by [journal name] because it… [specific reference to the journal’s Aims & Scope]. __________.  
    %   [Please explain in your own words the significance and novelty of the work, the problem that is being addressed, and why the manuscript belongs in this journal. Do not simply insert your abstract into your cover letter! Briefly describe the research you are reporting in your paper, why it is important, and why you think the readership of the journal would be interested in it.]
    
    In this paper we show that smoking is bath for health. This is significant because bad health decreases life expectancy and years of good life.
    
    We believe that this manuscript is appropriate for publication by \journal\ as we need to get this published somewhere.
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% EDIT ABOVE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    % [[Revise or delete any of the following standard statements used in cover letters]]
    We declare that this manuscript is original, has not been published before and is not currently being considered for publication elsewhere. We know of no conflicts of interest associated with this publication, and there has been no significant financial support for this work that could have influenced its outcome. As corresponding author, I confirm that the manuscript has been read and approved for submission by all the named authors:\coauthorsandemails.
    
    % Suggestion for referees
    
    In case you found it useful, my coauthors and I would like to suggest as possible referees \referees. % You may access their homepages by clicking at the titles.
    
    
    
    % [[Add any other statements/information required by the journal here.]]
    We hope you find our manuscript fit for publication in your journal and look forward to hearing from you.
    
    \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
    
    Kind Regards,
    \vspace{-0.4\baselineskip}
    
    \signature
    
    \vspace{-0.7\baselineskip}
    \fromname
    
    \begin{comment}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \vspace{1\baselineskip}
    
    Enclosed:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Article Manuscript
    \item Title Page
    \end{itemize}
    \end{comment}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do not change `\parskip` and `\parindent` manually. Use KOMA-Script option `parskip` with one of the values `full`, `full-`, `full+` or `full*`.  Load package `hyperref` after the other packages.

Comment: Do you mean ```\documentclass[...parskip=full-]{scrartcl}``` and something similiar to replace ```\parindent``` ?

Comment: Either `\documentclass[parskip=full-]{scrartcl}` or `\KOMAoptions{parskip=full-}`. `parskip=full-` changes the `\parindent` to `0pt`, too.

Comment: @esdd now reflected in the answer